# Why does this async lambda function invocation not compile in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I seem to be missing something really basic in my understanding. I am trying to call an async function that will take a `Func<T>` passed in by the caller, in case if the async function doesn't find a value in the cache. I am really puzzled as to why my code won't compile.

My calling code is as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Task<string>> dataFetcher = async () =>
    {
        string myCacheValue = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        return myCacheValue;
    };

    MyCache<string> cache = new MyCache<string>();

    string mValue = cache.GetOrCreateAsync("myCacheKey", dataFetcher).Result;

}
```

MyCache is as follows

```
internal class MyCache<T> where T: class
{
    private Cache localCache = null;

    public MyCache()
    {
        localCache = new Cache();
    }
    public T GetOrCreate(string cacheKey, Func<T> doWork)
    {
        T cachedObject = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cacheKey))
            return cachedObject;

        cachedObject = localCache.Get(cacheKey) as T;

        if (null == cachedObject)
        {
            cachedObject = doWork();
        }

        localCache.Add(cacheKey, cachedObject, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

        return cachedObject;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetOrCreateAsync(string cacheKey, Func<T> doWork)
    {
        T cachedObject = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cacheKey))
            return cachedObject;

        try
        {
            cachedObject = await Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(doWork);
            localCache.Add(cacheKey, cachedObject, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            cachedObject = null;
        }
        finally
        {
        }

        return cachedObject;
    }
}
```

In the calling code the line

```
string mValue = cache.GetOrCreateAsync("myCacheKey", dataFetcher).Result;
```

gives me a compile time error `Argument 2: cannot convert from System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> to System.Func<string>`

I am at a loss as to what am I missing out on? If someone could help that will be great!

Thanks
~KD

Comment: Added my edits. Sorry this is my first time posting to stack overflow and I just don't know how to use all the various features yet. Thanks!

Comment: `GetOrCreateAsync` expect `Func<T> doWork` where `T` is `string`, but you pass in `Func<Task<string>> dataFetcher`. So, the error is just about that: `cannot convert from System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> to System.Func<string>`.

Comment: `dataFetcher` type is `Func<Task<string>>` however your `GetOrCreateAsync()` requires `Func<T>` which probably should be `Func<Task<T>>` (not sure if that changes logic in method tho.

Comment: If I don't use `Func<Task<string>>` then I can't use it as an async. Since I want to await on doWork, by starting a new task, I will have to use `Func<Task<string>>`. isn't it?

Comment: You did not await on doWork, you wrap it into a new task and await that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an overloaded method and pass a `Func<Task<T>>` argument to it. Then you can await on that result (which is a `Task<T>`).

```
public async Task<T> GetOrCreateAsync(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> doWorkAsync)
{
    T cachedObject = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cacheKey))
        return cachedObject;

    try
    {
        cachedObject = await doWorkAsync();
        localCache.Add(cacheKey, cachedObject, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        cachedObject = null;
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    return cachedObject;
}
```

Comment: Duh!! I got confused! Thank you for the explanation! I wasn't just able to see it.