# How to fix this .NET method that has a func as an argument?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, func

I have the following method

```
public async Task<dynamic> FooAsync(dynamic parameters, 
                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{..}
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to call it properly using *this* method:

```
public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(Func<dynamic, CancellationToken, Task<dynamic>> func)
{
    try
    {
        await func(); // Doesn't compile. Says it missing the 2 arguments.
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        ..
    }
}
```

e.g. code that passes `FooAsync` to `TryAsync` ..

```
public async Task PewPewAsync(..)
{
    ...
    // TODO: Get this to work/compile :(
    var result = await TryAsync(FooAsync(parameters, cancellationToken);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Found [almost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558237/why-does-this-async-lambda-function-invocation-not-compile-in-c)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a delegate that takes two parameters (`dynamic` and `CancellationToken`) and you're trying to invoke it with zero arguments.

Depending on what you want to do, you can either make `TryAsync` accept the two parameters and then pass them when calling it:

```
public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(
    Func<dynamic, CancellationToken, Task<dynamic>> func,
    dynamic parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        return await func(parameters, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        ..
    }
}

TryAsync(FooAsync, parameters, cancellationToken);
```

Or you can take a delegate that does not have any parameters and use a lambda when calling it:

```
public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(Func<Task<dynamic>> func)
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        ..
    }
}

TryAsync(() => FooAsync(parameters, cancellationToken));
```

Comment: Hmm.. I get the red-squiggly line _under_ `FooAsync` when trying to make that call... ref: http://i.imgur.com/9FZWQha.png  (NOTE: ignore the recrussive error calls. I just whipped this up to get a screen shot.)

Comment: It works fine if the type of `parameters` is not `dynamic`. But if you want to have it `dynamic`, you'll have to add a cast: `TryAsync((Func<dynamic, CancellationToken, Task<dynamic>>)FooAsync, parameters, cancellationToken);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(Func<dynamic, CancellationToken, Task<dynamic>> func, dynamic parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await func(parameters, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        ..
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
public async Task PewPewAsync(..)
{
    ...
    var result = await TryAsync(FooAsync, parameters, cancellationToken);
    ...
}
```

The reason is that you need to pass the parameters to the function you want to call/wrap separately so you can pass them to the actual invocation. In your original code, you're calling the function and passing the return value as a parameter to `TryAsync`, and not passing a reference to the function itself.

Comment: Hmm ... I cannot get the first line to compile?? ref: http://i.imgur.com/bR955Ih.png

Comment: My bad, i missed the type declarations of some of the function parameters. I've updated the code again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve with that TryAsync. One method is shown in another answer. The other way is

```
public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(Func<Task<dynamic>> func) {
    try {
        var result = await func();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }
}
```

Call like this

```
var result = await TryAsync(() => FooAsync(parameters, cancellationToken));
```

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: @svick Well you might have noticed original code also won't compile... But ok, added "return null".

Comment: I meant that `TryAsync` takes a `Func<Task<dynamic>>`, but you're passing in `Task<dynamic>`.

Comment: Well you are right that it will work incorrectly. But you are wrong that it won't compile - it will happily compile and then fail at runtime (because of dynamic), just tried. That is actually why I missed that error :)

Comment: Not that it matters now, but whether it compiles or not depends on the type of `parameters`, which doesn't have to be `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends - when do you want to execute `FooAsync`?

In `TryAsync` or before? If you want execute everything in `TryAsync`, you could use:

```
    public async Task<dynamic> FooAsync(dynamic parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return await Task.FromResult("x");
    }

    public async Task<dynamic> TryAsync(Func<Task<dynamic>> func) {
        try {
            return await func(); // Doesn't compile. Says it missing the 2 arguments.
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    public async Task PewPewAsync() {
        var parameters = "x";
        var cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
        var result = await TryAsync(() => FooAsync(parameters, cancellationToken));
    }
```